# Is it safe to create an instance of a class in its metaclass in Python?

Tags: python, metaclass

How safe is it to create an instance of a class in the metaclass constructors (`__new__` and `__init__`)? I'm specifically interested for Python 2.7, but what Python 3 does is also welcome.

The [Python data model docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) sound like they're written for the normal class instance creation case, and I'm not really sure how the rules might be subtly different when its occurring in a metaclass.

For example, lets say I have code like this:

```
class Meta(type):
  NEWED = []
  INITED_BEFORE = []
  INITED_AFTER = []
  def __new__(meta, name, bases, dict):
    cls = super(Meta, meta).__new__(meta, name, bases, dict)
    instance = cls()
    Meta.NEWED.append(instance)
    return cls

  def __init__(cls, name, bases, dict):
    Meta.INITED_BEFORE.append(cls())
    super(Meta, cls).__init__(name, bases, dict)
    Meta.INITED_AFTER.append(cls())

class Foo(object):
  __metaclass__ = Meta
```

At which points, if any, is it safe to construct an instance of Foo while the metaclass is constructing it, and what sort of caveats are there?

One suspicion I have is that, if Foo inherited other classes, or was subclassed, and those other classes had their own metaclass, then calling `cls()` in any of the metaclass methods would be calling it on a not-yet-finished class object. Is that true?

Comment: I don't think it's really documented in Python 2.x, so the only way to answer this is to examine the implementation for every implementation you care about, or to just write the test cases you care about and test them with every implementation you care about.

Comment: I'll have to double-check, but I'm pretty sure that `instance = cls()` in your `__new__` method is going to create an infinite loop, as calling `cls()` will then call `__new__` for that new instance you're trying to create.

Comment: The metaclass system in Python 3.x _has_ been thoroughly worked through and documented, but that doesn't do you any good if you want to stick with 2.7, of course.

Comment: P.S. I assume this is Python 2.x, since you're inheriting from `object` in class Foo. Also, I think your `Meta.INITED_BEFORE = cls()` line is not quite right; did you mean `Meta.INITED_BEFORE.append(cls())`? (Same for the `INITED_AFTER` line as well.)

Comment: @rmunn calling `cls()` will not call the `__new__` for the *metaclass*.  That is only called at class creation time.

Comment: Ignore my comment about `instance = cls()` creating an infinite loop; I was wrong. I tried to edit the comment, but I was just outside the 5-minute window when editing comments is allowed. I'll let it stand rather than deleting it, but just ignore it.

Comment: Yes, python 2.7, but knowing what py3 does is good, too. Yes, there were supposed to be append calls there, fixed it, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> One suspicion I have is that, if Foo inherited other classes, or was subclassed, and those other classes had their own metaclass, then calling cls() in any of the metaclass methods would be calling it on a not-yet-finished class object. Is that true?

That is true, to the extent that in the metaclass's `__new__`, its `__init__` won't have been called yet.  Your metaclass has an `__init__`, as might any subclass, so you should make sure that gets called first.  So I wouldn't try to make an instance of a class that hasn't been fully instantiated yet.

One thing you might do is manually call the metaclass's `__init__` from within `__new__`.  But you would have to set a flag or something in `__init__` to make sure that the class doesn't get `__init__`'d twice.  There might be a more clever way too that I'm not thinking of at the moment.